# Как сделать пробелы в форме ввода

Tags: html

Вот многие формы ввода умеют разделять числа по 4 символа. Как это сделать?

Например данные карточки 0001 2563 1425 2365

Comment: Почитайте про плагин  [jquery mask](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите результат вашей маски:

```js
$("#foo").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999");
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/v1.13.4/dist/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input id="foo" type="text">
```

Comment: У плагина глюк. Если поле пустое, то при нажатии не на цифру получаем несколько пробелов.

Comment: @Visman: Средства не нативные, потому и глюки. Вот, к примеру, для [angular](http://candreoliveira.github.io/bower_components/angular-mask/examples/index.html#/). Там тоже вы найдёте немало глюков. Как говорится: "вам шашечки или ехать?" :)

Answer (score 0):

а еще есть более легкий VanillaJS https://github.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker